# Calling Modules with Use declaration

Tags: module, fortran

I am trying to use a few modules using

```
Use Strn, Mindy, Info
```

However the GNU compiler is complaining

```
Syntax error in USE statement at (1)
```

Comment: Just to confirm: `Strn`, `Mindy` and `Info` are all modules that you wish to access?

Comment: Yes, they are all modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well the standard, each module must be on its own line. So you should have

```
use Strn
use Mindy
use Info
```

instead of

```
Use Strn, Mindy, Info
```

Here is the copy paste from the WD 1539-1 f2008 draft, and you can see that there is only one module name per use statement.

```
use-stmt  is USE [ [ , module-nature ] :: ] module-name [ , rename-list ]
          or USE [ [ , module-nature ] :: ] module-name ,
          ONLY : [ only-list ]

module-nature  is INTRINSIC
                or NON INTRINSIC

rename         is local-name => use-name
               or OPERATOR (local-deﬁned-operator ) =>
               OPERATOR (use-deﬁned-operator )

only           is generic-spec
               or only-use-name
               or rename

only-use-name is use-name
```